# In an input array in Java, how do I find the number of pairs of values that are equal?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, time, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to make an O(nlogn) algorithm that determines the number of pairs of
values in an input array that are equal. What I was thinking of doing was storing each value of the array in another variable and continue comparing the current value to the previous values and see if there's a match and if there is then the counter goes up by one.

```
int current value; 
int previous value; 
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
        current value = array[k]
        previous value = array[k-1]
```

What I'm confused about is the fact that the running time has to be O(nlogn) so I'm wondering if that's the right kind of method to use for a problem like this or if there's a better and more convenient way of doing this.

Pseudo code:

```
n = array.length
for k - 1 to n do
    if k == k-1 
    then
increment counter by 1
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pairs that are equal"?  How many pairs would you say { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, } has?

Comment: It's supposed to find two numbers that are equal in the array and once it finds those two numbers then it counts that as one pair that are equal. So in this example it has 2 pairs that are equal.

Comment: It's very easy if the array is sorted. Are you allowed to sort the array?

Comment: Yes. Do I just sort the array and then compare each value?

Comment: Yes, and the sort is O(nlogn).

Comment: Would it look like the Pseudo code above?

Comment: Why don't you store them in HashMap where key would be the value and value their frequency of occurring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort array and compare adjacent values, it's one option. You'll have complexity of `O(n*log(n))` then.

Another option is to track already visited elements using temporary `HashSet` and result `HashMap` as a counter for pairs:

```
public static <T> Map<T, Integer> findPairs(List<T> elements) {
    Set<T> tracked = new HashSet<>();
    Map<T, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (T element : elements)
        if (!tracked.add(element)) {
            result.merge(element, 1, Math::addExact);
            tracked.remove(element);
        }
    return result;
}
```

This methods gives you `O(n)` because insertion and removal from `HashSet` and `HashMap` is `O(1)` *on average*, but `O(n)` in worst case. If it's important for you to have `O(n*log(n))` in worst case you should select first option as well as select sorting algorithm accordingly. Some sorting algorithms have O(n<sup>2</sup>) as a worst case complexity.